# How can I assign permissions with modules to a bot?

Tags: c, dll, bots, discord

I want to setup a discord bot for a friend who mixes music. Using a existing bot I have been able to make it work. However only I can issue commands. Every time I try to define permission as suggested by the creator it returns with a error saying "Don't know user (the actual module permission route command)"

I have tried summarizing the permissions in a lot of ways. Also looked up a lot about .json modules and the syntax. In case the description that came with it was wrong but I was unable to find anything useful. Not experienced with writing a bot but I also looked into maybe making a .js config and put commands etc in that since .js might be easier for me to use. But It seems like a huge workaround for a syntax error. I am not sure what the parent module for commands is so I tried a number of lines based of reflector when reading the .dll.

The commands I gave to the bot following the suggested syntax (aParentModule.aChildModule.aCommand(arg1,arg2,arg3))
"@BOT permissions assign Admin Voice"

Reply:That doesn't look quite right, I will ignore these entries: Voice
I don't know this person.

I tells me the person issue a lot so I think I am not dividing the request properly there. Can't find out how to though.

@BOT permissions assign Yourcall ,voice,join

Reply: That doesn't look quite right, I will ignore these entries: ,voice,join
I don't know this person.

The bot I am using can be found on github for reference: https://github.com/BinkanSalaryman/Discord-Audio-Stream-Bot

Commands from config.json with the permission command

"text": {
    "commands": {
      "botAgent": "tomoko",
      "permissions": {
        "defaultPermissions": "!bot.stop() !guild.leave() help.commands(path) !permissions.assign(USER_OR_ROLE,PERMISSIONS) utils.ping(host)",
        "userPermissions": {},
        "rolePermissions": {}
      }

The error I get from the bot "Tomoko.json"

```
"warning_badUser": "I don't know this person.",
```

I want to be able to give join and leave command to a specific role and not just the bot creator To do that the bot needs to stop seeing the commands as user names from what I can see based of the response messages.

Comment: There is a "permissions syntax" command that shows the syntax rules in case anyone needs it for reference I could not include it in the original question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to simply ask the project owner by reaching out to them on Discord or posting an issue on the repo? Unless someone here uses that project, they'd have to read through the code to figure out how exactly it works.

Comment: Yes. I did not want at first since it seems it's more a case of me not putting in the right order of "permission". So I decided to solve it myself. His contact link also seems to not work. I am not really a programmer so it's hard to judge for me it's a noobie user issue or not. Since no matter what I give as command it still reads the command as a person.